# Different way to open a PDF than from current SD?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I know there are many similar questions, but I need specifics. I originally wanted my app to open PDFS within the app itself, but I have settled to send an intent activity to adobe reader. I am currently opening PDFS by looking for the file on the device itself. Is there a way I can have the PDFS in my app, and create a folder on the users device, and then look for them? or something similar? Obvisouly the user isn't going to have the PDF already installed on their device. Here is my current code.

```
Intent intent7 = new Intent();                 
        intent7.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");    
        intent7.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Auto-example.pdf")), "application/pdf");  
        startActivity(intent7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can have the PDFS in my app, and create a folder on the users device, and then look for them?

You can put the PDF in internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), then [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve them via a `ContentProvider`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrates serving a PDF from internal storage (copied there from `assets/`) and viewing it in the user's chosen PDF viewer. There is also [an Android training module](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) covering this.

With respect to the code that you have, please use `ACTION_VIEW` as your `Intent` action (e.g., pass that to the constructor) and delete the `setPackage()` line.